# JS and CSS are not loading

Tags: javascript, css, jsp

When I am trying to access my JSP page, CSS and JS are not loading. I am using below syntax for the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=WebContent/CSS/example.css />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=WebContent/CSS/bootstrap.min.css />

<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="header.jsp" />


    <jsp:include page="Footer.jsp" />
    <script src="WebContent/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="WebContent/js/jquery.min.js"></script>   
</body>
```

My css is placed under WebContent -> CSS folder.

I already tried using context path using **${pageContext.request.contextPath}**

I also tried using **""**  value in href tag, but of no use.

I am stuck in this issue from last two days... :(
please help

Comment: Missing " for the href attribute of your slylesheets

Comment: Are you able to browse straight to the .css files anyway?  `http://localhost:12345/yourpath/WebContent/CSS/example.css`

Comment: have u tried (href="../WebContent/CSS/example.css")

Comment: Small correction I am using below format for css:

Comment: Better to refer file from the root of your site, using "/" before anythong else

Comment: I tried giving " in href but did not help.....

Comment: No I am not able to browse css directly.....

Comment: When I am trying to browse css directly, the page is getting redirected to my default page. and try to search the default page in CSS folder.... :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/example.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>


<jsp:include page="Footer.jsp"/>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=WebContent/CSS/example.css />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=WebContent/CSS/bootstrap.min.css />
```

use this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/example.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css" />
```